# How to prevent a dynamically generated jQuery draggable div, with fixed position, from being dragged off the screen completely?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I am using a combination of jQuery accordion and draggable for a menu.

here's the sample markup:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <h3>One</h3>
    <div>The One</div>
    <h3>Two</h3>
    <div>The Two</div>
    <h3>Three</h3>
    <div>The Three</div>
    <h3>Four</h3>
    <div>The Four</div>
</div>
```

and the js:

```
jQuery('.wrapper').accordion({
            heightStyle: "content",
            navigation: true, 
            collapsible: true,
            animated: "bounceslide", 
        }).draggable({
            axis: "y",
});
```

you can see the sample [<del>jsfiddle here</del>](http://jsfiddle.net/g4vxL/)

updated fiddle: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g4vxL/2/)

desired end result(currently static, I would like to implement it dynamically): [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g4vxL/4/)

The menu is dynamically generated - I do not know how many items will be in the accordion ahead of time. Sometimes the total wrapper height will exceed the total document height so I wanted to allow the users to move the wrapper vertically using jQuery draggable. However, currently you can click and drag the wrapper div off screen. I would like to be able to constrain the bottom and top of the wrapper so the first and last h3 element is always showing on the screen respectively (with the rest of the wrapper div being hidden off screen)

I tried using containment the constrain the wrapper by calculating the height of the wrapper
and subtracting the height of the h3 from it but to no avail:

```
var minHeight = jQuery('.wrapper').height() - jQuery('.wrapper h3').height();
var maxHeight = jQuery(document).height() - jQuery('.wrapper h3').height();
```

changing draggable to:

```
.draggable({
                axis: "y",
         containment: [0, -minHeight, 250, maxHeight]
});
```

Any ideas on how to implement this?

**[EDIT]**

Here's the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g4vxL/2/)

**[EDIT 2]**

Seems I was on the right track with containment...Here's the end result using static containment values

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g4vxL/4/)

basically using

```
 containment: [0, -540, 250,270]
```

This shows the desired end result behavior...now all I need to do is figure out the correct math behind this to make it behave like this dynamically

Comment: `containment:"document"` ??? http://jsfiddle.net/g4vxL/1/

Comment: Why not my just put the accordian in a div with overflow-y:auto and forget about draggable?

Comment: @A. Wolff if there are too many elements in the accordion I won't be able to get to the ones on the bottom using this...that's why I need to move the top of the wrapper so only the last h3 element and the associated div are showing

Comment: @MichaelMikowski I don't want scrollbars on the outer div...this is a simplified model and I wanted to avoid the use of scrollbars on the outer wrapper element

Comment: @zoranc i've hard time to figure out how you can get all elements visible if its exceed the document height. I don't really understand what you are looking for. Maybe you could provide a more relevant jsfiddle with more elements

Comment: ah the position of the wrapper element is fixed...so the height of the document is determined by the actual content

Comment: updated the fiddle so this clarifies what I am after a bit more : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g4vxL/2/)

Comment: you can keep dragging the whole wrapper element up. However, I want to prevent the user from dragging the wrapper element's last h3 element above the top of the visible range...they wont be able to drag it back at that point unless they refresh the screen to reset everything.

Answer (score 0):

The below is using `containment: "window"` and seems to work for me, but I'm not sure if it is exactly what you are looking for.

```
jQuery('.wrapper').accordion({
    heightStyle: "content",
    navigation: true,
    collapsible: true,
    animated: "bounceslide", 
}).draggable({
    containment:"window",
});
```

Comment: Just saw A. Wollf's answer, and your response - sorry about that.

Comment: Does iframeFix: true work for you? [JSFidle](http://jsfiddle.net/g4vxL/3/)  This keeps the divs in 'focus' when the mouse returns to the screen.

Comment: no seems I can still move the entire menu off screen with no means to get it back

Answer (score 0):

Try `containment:"body"`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g4vxL/6/

Comment: won't work in this case...check out this updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g4vxL/2/) that mirrors my situation better than the jsfiddle I posted initially